# Why is the letter S of the word "sure" - pronounced as "sh"?

Tags: pronunciation

Why is the letter S in the word "**s**ure" is pronounced as "sh"?

If we compare most of the words in English (for instance: surface, surname, sum, sir, soup, sun etc.) then we can easily see that the pronunciation of "**s**ure" is an exception.

Comment: There's also "sugar".

Comment: Related ELU question: [Why are “sugar” and “sure” pronounced with an SH?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33434)

Answer (score 19):

Very interesting question, the reason is in the etymological evolution of spelling and pronunciation of terms and vowels  with a  French origin.

Here is an extract from ***[The oddest English spellings, part 18: Why sure and sugar?](http://blog.oup.com/2011/11/sugar/)***  by linguist and etymologist Anatoly  Liberman:

> - **The vowel occurring in French *sure* was alien to most Middle English dialects, including the dialect of London,** and, as the name of the modern English letter U shows, yu replaced French u in borrowed words.
> - We can observe this substitution even in such a recent loanword as *menu* (and compare *nubile* and other nu- words).  **Once *sure* appeared in English, it turned into *syure*, and a similar change happened in *sugar* (*syugar*)**.
> - **Later, syu– developed into sh–** (compare *bless you*, *session*, and *Asia*, regardless of whether you have a voiced or a voiceless middle in the last of them, for the voicing is secondary).

Comment: I don't hear many people pronouncing bless as blesh unless they're running their words together.

Comment: @JAB I don't think anyone pronounces bless by itself that way, but I've heard people say bless you like that.

Comment: @MattSamuel to use it in a sentence it goes "Ah-tissue - bless you" :D

Comment: The French connection is the important point here.  Actually, the "syu" sound familiar to English speakers in "bless you" is how you should pronounce sure in French (and the French spelling is *sûr*).

Comment: The term *insurance* is another example.

Comment: @wim What do you mean? That's not how we pronounce *sûr*, it's /iu/ instead of /y/ (which does not exist in many many languages)

Answer (score 3):

'[Palatalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change))' (or '[yod-coalescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-coalescence)') is what caused *sure* and *sugar* to have /ʃ/ instead of /s/.

It's a process whereby the clusters /tj/, /dj/, /sj/ and /zj/ coalesce into /t͡ʃ/, /d͡ʒ/, /ʃ/ and /ʒ/, respectively. It often happens when an alveolar obstruent (/t/, /d/, /s/, /z/) is immediately followed by a /j/.

In Modern English, it mostly affects weak syllables for instance the last syllable in 'mission' /ˈmɪ.ʃ(ə)n/.
The letter 'u' used to be (still in some words like 'sue' in some accents) pronounced /juː/ (the same as the word *you*), but later on it either got dropped (*yod-dropping*) or coalesced with the following /j/ (*yod-coalescence*).

The sequence **alveolar obstruent + [ju-]** in primary stressed syllables simplified either by coalescence or by preservation of the alveolar obstruent and loss of palatality (loss of /j/).

In the sequence [sju-], the only two items in English with stressed stem-initial [sj-]
to [ʃ-] change are *sure* and *sugar* and their derivatives (in *sure* and *sugar*, the /s/ coalesced with the following /j/ and yielded /ʃ/).
The /j/ in other words like *super, suit, suet* etc., got dropped (historically) in most accents and only the alveolar obstruent /s-/ remained. So *super, suit, suet* etc., don't have the cluster /sj/ (or /ʃ/).

Other examples of palatalisation include *gra**du**al*, *sol**die**r*, *pas**si**on*, *na**tu**re*, *eli**sio**n* etc.

---

<sup>/j/ is the sound as in ***y**ou*.

/t͡ʃ/ as in ***ch**ip*.

/d͡ʒ/ as in ***j**am*.

/ʒ/ as in *eli**sio**n*

/ʃ/ as in ***sh**ip*.</sup>